# Postfix E-Mail transfer doesn`t work - SASL Authentification failed

Tags: postfix, exchange, sasl

I want to use the postfix MTA to send E-mails from my Nagios monitoring system to the contacts. However, i get the follwing error, if a mail will be send

```
May 28 16:20:29 op5-system postfix/qmgr[1932]: EFF031FFE36: from=<email@address.com>, size=1040, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 28 16:20:29 op5-system postfix/error[4062]: EFF031FFE36: to=<email@address.com>, relay=none, delay=2083, delays=2082/0.08/0/0.03, dsn=4.7.3, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: SASL authentication failed; server mail.server.com[10.0.7.3] said: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful)
```

The password is correct, the files sasl_passwd and generic are postmap and all necessary packages are installed

**main.cf:**

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain, login, ntlm
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
relayhost = mail.server.com
```

**sasl_passwd:**

```
mail.server.com user@password
```

Many thanks for every answer!

Comment: The format of `sasl_passwd` entry is `mail. server username:password`. --> using single colon **:** instead of @ to split username and password. See http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl_enable

Comment: Thanks it works. Sorry for this needless question. I forgot this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sasl_passwd uses : instead of @ to split username and password

```
mail.server.com user:password
```

See comment from masegaleoh